# uid 10645 does not have any of [android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION]

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderclient

i am using this in fragment and here is my code

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLiveLocation() {
        if(GpsUtils.isGpsEnable(requireActivity())) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(requireActivity(), new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.e("essss",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "please enable gps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

and here is my manifest file permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but i am getting this exception uid 10645 does not have any of [android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION].

Comment: Did you add code to request the user at runtime to confirm those permissions?